# How do I create a responsive pie chart using Vega/Vega lite?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vega-lite, vega

I would like to create a Pie Chart in Vega-Lite. I have already created one, but I would like its radius to be responsive to the screen size on which the web page is displayed.

```js
            vegaEmbed("#pie-chart", {
                $schema: "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
                autosize: {
                    type: "fit",
                    contains: "padding",
                },
                resize: true,
                layer: [
                    {mark: {type: "arc", innerRadius: 35, outerRadius: 80}},
                    {
                        mark: {type: "text", radius: 57.5, fill: "white"},
                        encoding: {
                            text: {field: "count", type: "nominal"},
                        },
                    },
                ],
                encoding: {
                    color: {
                        field: "name",
                        type: "nominal",
                    },
                    theta: {
                        field: "count",
                        type: "quantitative",
                        stack: true,
                    },
                },
                data: {
                    values: [
                        {
                            name: "a",
                            count: 21,
                        },
                        {
                            name: "b",
                            count: 6,
                        },
                        {
                            name: "c",
                            count: 3,
                        },
                        {
                            name: "d",
                            count: 3,
                        },
                        {
                            name: "e",
                            count: 2,
                        },
                        {
                            name: "f",
                            count: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            name: "g",
                            count: 2,
                        },
                        {
                            name: "h",
                            count: 1,
                        },
                    ],
                },
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Data visualizer</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="pie-chart"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

I've considered creating a JavaScript function which, based on the screen width, dynamically re-generates the graph based on the width with a variable radius, but that solution seems overly complex and prone to errors. Does anyone have a recommendation for the way in which I may make the size of the pie-chart responsive?
In addition to that, as you may have noticed the left side of the chart is clipped, presumably due to the inclusion of a legend. Does anyone happen to know of a quick fix that may fix this without manually setting the size of the graph's container?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you set `resize: true` outside the `autosize` specification. Perhaps you intended this?

```
     autosize: {
                    type: "fit",
                    contains: "padding",
                    resize: true,
                },
```

Comment: Good catch! But I still need to manually set the radius of the pie-chart, as it is defined numerically in my original question.